# How do I redraw a barcode object on a pdf document?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm trying to make a pdf document that will display the current date and 5 business days from now in the form of a barcode object.

I was able to get the value of my barcode to update to the current date with a bit of javascript:

```
var today = new Date();
event.value = util.printd("dd-mmm-yy", today);
```

But of course that just sets the value of the barcode and not the appearance of it so it just displays as text. Does the barcode object have an attribute or function to redraw it or update the appearance?

I used this bit of code to get the 5 business days from today works the same as above:

```
var today = new Date();
var numToAdd = 5;
var i = 1;

for (i = 1; i <= numToAdd; i++) {
  today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
  if (today.getDay() === 6) {
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 2);
  }
  else if (today.getDay() === 0) {
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
  }
}
event.value = util.printd("dd-mmm-yy", today);
```

Comment: What type of barcode? Most 1D barcodes can be represented with a font.

Comment: @KevinBrown In this case I've been using the qr code format but any barcode works, I considered the font option but I don't have access to install fonts on this computer so that's not an option. I'm using Nitro Pro to create my PDF https://www.gonitro.com/user-guide/pro/article/create-a-barcode-field but could not find any documentation about methods or attributes of the barcode field object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print from html to PDF here is an example just for Monday but you can  remove the unwanted outputs and add your other days by multiple entries

For details and options like colours see https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/ and  https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode

```js
var now = new Date();
var next_week_start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+(8 - now.getDay()));
var barStringMonday = next_week_start.toDateString()

JsBarcode("#barcodeMonday", barStringMonday , {format: "code39"});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.5/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
Hello Dear World!</br>
Here are your Bare Codes
<p>
SVG<svg id="barcodeMonday"></svg>
</p>
Canvas<canvas id="barcodeMonday"></canvas>
<p>
Image<img id="barcodeMonday" alt="code39 barcode value as of Monday" />
</p>
```

Comment: I already have the PDF and the barcodes are you saying there is no way to do it in the pdf? I just need them to be re-drawn when the date changes, changing the value of the barcode turns it into text because a field's value and the appearance of that value are two seperate things in a pdf

Comment: Still no idea how to do it in a PDF so I took your advice and created an html file to do it instead and just generated the qr codes from scratch rather than trying to get them to update automatically

Comment: Skipped all that nonsense by using barcode-generator.org lol  
<img id="qr4">  
<script>  
function dateToYMD(date) {  
    var strArray=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', Dec'];  
    var d = date.getDate();  
    var m = strArray[date.getMonth()];  
    var y = date.getFullYear() - 2000;  
    return d + '-' + m + '-' + y;  
}  
  
var today = new Date();  
document.getElementById("qr4").src = "https://www.barcode-generator.org/phpqrcode/getCode.php?cht=qr&chl=" + dateToYMD(today);  
</script>